# How to position columns on the bottom of the row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, position, row

I want to position the grey box on the bottom of the row, like this:

[image]

I tried to do it via some helper-classes like:
`.pos-relative { position: relative; }` applied on the row.
`.col-bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }` applied on the column.

That is what I get:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row no-gutters pos-relative">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-bottom">
        <div class="design-box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-3">
        <div class="second-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.second-box {
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    height: 30em;
}

.pos-relative {
    position: relative;
}

.col-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Would be nice if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not quite clear what's the point. You have to rows each devided in two columns and you want the black box to be centered on the bottom of left column in a first row or what?

Comment: I have TWO columns inside ONE row and I want to position the FIRST column (black box) to the bottom of the whole row, which applies the hight of the SECOND column (white box). Any of my tries resulted in overlapping columns. Got it?

Comment: Yeap, I got it. Well, you can try to do it a little bit more tricky. Place the black box in the second row and set a negative margin-top, so it will overlap with the upper row and it'll looks like the box actually placed there. I suppose, you'll still need to use absolute positioning for doing that.